# Constant expression required

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know it is possible to set text in static array in the parenthesis like the following code.

```
Sub test()
          Dim myarray(1 to 10 , Costs to Revenues )
          myarray(1,Costs) = ...
          ...
End sub
```

Comment: What do `Costs` and `Revenues` represent here?

Comment: Is there an `Enum` there defining values for `Costs` and `Revenues`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible

```
Sub Sample()
    Const Costs = 1
    Const Revenues = 2

    Dim myarray(1 To 10, Costs To Revenues)

    myarray(1, Costs) = "Sid"
    myarray(1, Revenues) = "Rout"

    MsgBox myarray(1, Costs)
    MsgBox myarray(1, Revenues)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only way to use an initializer for an array in VBA is with the [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) function.  Note that it has to be declared as Variant:

```
Sub ArrayDemo()

    Dim strings As Variant
    strings = Array("one", "two", "three")

    Dim counter As Integer
    For counter = LBound(strings) To UBound(strings)
        Debug.Print strings(counter)
    Next counter

End Sub
```